# Parsing RFC-3339 date string to time.Time

Tags: date, go

How to convert string date format to date, I have date string in format of:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Following I tried with no luck.

```
t, err := time.Parse("%Y-%m-%d", "2011-01-19")
t, err := time.Parse("YYYY-MM-DD", "2011-01-19")
t, err := time.Parse("2016-01-20", "2011-01-19")
```

all above statements are giving parse errors.

Comment: the last example works, but you made an error in `2016` should be `2006`, and `20` should be `02` instead. so: `t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2011-01-19")`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please read the documentation of the [time.Parse](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse):

> The layout defines the format by showing how the reference time, defined to be
>
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
>
> would be interpreted if it were the value; it serves as an example of the input format. The same interpretation will then be made to the input string.

So the correct format is

```
t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2011-01-19")
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to using a literal `2006-01-02` time format, you reduce errors by creating a constant similar to how Go does it in the `time` package.

The `YYYY-MM-DD` format is defined as `full-date` in [RFC-3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5) as follows (order adjusted):

```
full-date       = date-fullyear "-" date-month "-" date-mday
date-fullyear   = 4DIGIT
date-month      = 2DIGIT  ; 01-12
date-mday       = 2DIGIT  ; 01-28, 01-29, 01-30, 01-31 based on
                          ; month/year
```

So you can create a constant like the following to go along with the built-in `time.RFC3339` and `time.RFC3339Nano` constants.

```
const RFC3339FullDate = "2006-01-02"
```

Then you can write the following:

```
t, err := time.Parse(RFC3339FullDate, "2011-01-19")
```

This is in the [`mogo/time/timeutil`](https://github.com/grokify/mogo/blob/master/time/timeutil/format.go) package, so you can write:

```
t, err := time.Parse(timeutil.RFC3339FullDate, "2011-01-19")
```

For reference, [`time/format.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/8da180f6cac51f6cb8a316b962f797dbaf7ee96f/src/time/format.go) contains the following constants:

```
const (
    ANSIC       = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"
    UnixDate    = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006"
    RubyDate    = "Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006"
    RFC822      = "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"
    RFC822Z     = "02 Jan 06 15:04 -0700" // RFC822 with numeric zone
    RFC850      = "Monday, 02-Jan-06 15:04:05 MST"
    RFC1123     = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"
    RFC1123Z    = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700" // RFC1123 with numeric zone
    RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
    RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
    Kitchen     = "3:04PM"
    // Handy time stamps.
    Stamp      = "Jan _2 15:04:05"
    StampMilli = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000"
    StampMicro = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000"
    StampNano  = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000000"
)
```