# Parsing time in golang. How to define correct layout?

Tags: parsing, layout, go, time

I am trying to parse time from string to time.Time type. I have following code:

```
s, _ := v.(string)
fmt.Println(s) //Gives: 2016-12-01T14:10:12Z
ttime, err := time.Parse("2006-01-01T07:00:00Z", s)
fmt.Println(err) //Gives: parsing time "2016-12-01T14:10:12Z" as "2006-01-01T07:00:00Z": cannot parse "14:10:12Z" as "T07:00:00Z
```

When I try change time layout:

```
s, _ := v.(string)
fmt.Println(s) //Gives: 2016-12-01T14:10:12Z
ttime, err := time.Parse("2006-01-01 07:00:00Z", s)
fmt.Println(err) //Gives: parsing time "2016-12-01T14:10:12Z": month out of range
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Your time layout format is incorrect, see ie http://stackoverflow.com/q/37937794/723693

Comment: Perfect thanks guys. `p.TimeParse("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z", v)` works